# Setting return type of method to type of calling object

Tags: java, generics

I have a method defined as follows:

```
public TYPE getById(ObjectId id) {
    return datastore.get(this.getClass(), id);
}
```

The method signature of `datastore.get()` is:

`<T, V> T get(Class<T> var1, V var2);`

How would I properly set the return type of my method?  Note that the object returned by `datastore.get()` is not the same type as my implementing class, it can be a subclass.  Therefore I want the return type to be specific to that class.

Comment: It will return specific to your class type. What question is?

Comment: I want the return type to be the same typing as the object that invokes it.  This object isn't necessarily the one implementing this method, it might be a subclass.

Comment: so, return the subclass type. What's the problem?

Comment: `Child1` and `Child2` both extend `Parent`, which implements this method.  I want to be able to declare: `Child1 c1 = new Child1().getById(123);`  Similarly, I want to be able to declare: `Child2 c2 = new Child2.getById(123)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is you want something like this:

```
public class Factory<T> {
  public T getById(ObjectId id) {
    return datastore.get(T, id);
  }
}

public class Class1Factory extends Factory<Class1> {
  public Class1 getById(ObjectId id) {
    return datastore.get(Class1.class, id);
  }
}
```

You have to use separate Factory classes as you cannot parameterize a class to itself. You cannot say:

```
public class Class1 extends Parent<Class1> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: "You cannot say:

public class Class1 extends Parent<Class1>" Of course you can.